# Where are sent emails stored in Dovecot?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

I've followed a tutorial on setting up [mail server](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mariadb-on-centos-7/) that uses Postfix, Dovecot and MariaDB. I have successfully sent and received emails. However I am not able to find the directory where sent email is stored. The mailbox location I specified in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf` is:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
```

Emails I receive for account support@mydomain.com are successfully stored in `/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/support/`. I haven't configured any client but Mutt yet. When I execute `mutt -f /var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/support/` I can inspect the emails I received.

What I haven't found a way to do it, is to inspect the emails I sent. When I send email using PHP they are sent to spam (surprisingly, when I use mutt, they are not) and I would like to inspect headers before they are sent over.
None of the files in `/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/support/` seem to belong to the sent email. Am I missing some configuration file or do I need to install additional software for storing sent emails?

Answer (score 3):

Your outgoing emails aren't saved anywhere by Dovecot. Dovecot is responsible for the retrieval of incoming Emails with protocols like IMAP or POP.

Outgoing emails are sent via Postfix with SMTP, or other interfaces.

Saving sent emails is something that most modern mail clients do, it does not happen automatically.

Comment: I've seen Postfix configurations with copy to self, then Procmail arranging those copies in a Sent folder. But it's still better job for a MUA.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I'm sure it is possible to write a Postfix mail filter that examines each mail and stores a copy somewhere. Such a filter probably already exists, but I don't think it is part of the default configuration.